# NEO-6M is working but it doesnt show data

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

So I'm having a little bit of difficulty here in my NEO-6M. `The problem is it doesn't show any data in my serial monitor.` My NEO-6M Led is already blinking so its already ok.

```
RX -> Pin3 , TX -> Pin4 , VCC -> 3.3v , GND -> GND
```

> Serial Monitor:
>   [image]

Code: 
*https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/examples/FullExample/FullExample.ino*

Comment: Have you crossed the serial lines? Arduino RX to GPS TX, Arduino TX to GPS RX

Comment: I have but I already fix it, does it broke my neo?

Comment: What do you mean? The lines need to be crossed. And having them not crossed most likely doesn't break it

Comment: Iv'e updated it now. @chrisl

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. On my first setup, I separate my GND of NEO-6M to Arduino and put connect it in breadboard that has powerboard on it because I thought it is only for electrical purposes but it doesn't since I encounter it.

Solution:

> The GND of every module must still connect on the Arduino.